# Asset manifest file "manifest.json" does not exist

Tags: symfony, symfony5, webpack-encore

On a symfony5 + webpack encore application I can't access the url of an image in a controller.

Webpack is working and i access the img in twig. (with versionning)
the manifest.json file exist, and I have build the assets

```
 $package = new Package(new JsonManifestVersionStrategy('C:\wamp64\www\svn\athena\public\build\manifest.json'));
 echo $package->getUrl('build/images/tree/families.png');
```

=> This is working with the direct file address of the manifest.

but with :

```
  $package = new Package(new JsonManifestVersionStrategy('manifest.json'));
```

or

```
$package = new Package(new JsonManifestVersionStrategy( '/build/manifest.json'));
```

=> I have the symfony exception : Asset manifest file "manifest.json" does not exist.

How can i make the manifest.json file address being relative ?
Thanks

assets.yaml

```
framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the path is [supposed to be absolute](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/cb03860eee66b6dbac9522e275cbb3f312f2be37/src/Symfony/Component/Asset/VersionStrategy/JsonManifestVersionStrategy.php#L31)...

You can inject the `Packages` service, that will be automatically configured:

```
use Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages;

public function controllerAction(Packages $packages) 
{
    $url = $packages->getUrl('build/images/tree/families.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works perfectly. I didn't know the packages service.